# Replacing specific symbol in a string in python, LaTeX to HTML without converter

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string, `w`, and I want to replace `"$_"` with `"<sub>"` and the first `"$"` after `"$_"` with `"</sub>"`. I need to do the same with replacing `"$^"` with `"<sup>"` and the `"$"` after it with `"</sup>"`. I tried `w.replace("$_", "<sub>")` and `w.replace("$", "</sub>")`, but I can't get only the first `"$"` after `"$_"` to be replaced with `"</sub>"`, only every `"$"` after it. The same follows for replacing `"$^"` with `"<sup>"`. How can I call only the `"$"` directly after the `"$_"` or `"$^"` indicators to change and not the rest?

Python code:

```
w = ["Li$_3$O$^cat$", "Al$_2$O$_3$", "ZnO", "H$_2$O+O$^3$"]
w = str(w)
if '$_' in w:
    w = w.replace("$_", "<sub>") 
    w = w.replace("$", "</sub>") 

if '$^' in w: 
    w = w.replace("$^","<sup>")
    w = w.replace("$","</sup>") 

print w
```

Desired output:

```
['Li< sub >3< /sub >O< sup >cat< /sup >', 
 'Al< sub >2< /sub >O< sub >3< /sub >', 
 'ZnO', 
 'H< sub >2< /sub >O+O< sup >3< /sup >']
```

Comment: Can you show exactly what you want your final output to be? I can't really follow your explanation.

Comment: Please give expected outputs for each of the input strings in your code.

Comment: Is it fair to assume you ultimately want to convert `$_...$` to `<sub>...</sub>` and `$^...$` to `<sup>...</sup>`, and that's why you don't want to prematurely replace ending `$` tags?

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry about all the confusion

Comment: Wait, is this LaTeX? If so, I'm sure there are already tools for converting LaTeX to HTML that would be better than rolling your own...maybe [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)?

Comment: This is Latex to HTML type deal but the project I am working on can't use LaTeX to HTML unfortunately. But yes it is the same deal with transforming Latex to HTML but without the converter, just replacing symbols

Comment: Why can't you use an existing tool?

Comment: Not sure, I was just told not to by my professor as part of a project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace all (non-overlapping) instances, you can do something like this:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\$_([^$]*)\$', r'<sub>\1</sub>', w)
```

This will find every instance of `$_(everything other than $)$` with `<sub>(everything other than $)</sub>`.

This means if you have something like `Li$_3$O$^cat$`, it will be converted to `Li<sub>3</sub>O$^cat$`.

If you also then want to convert `$^...$` to `<sup>...</sup>`, you can apply a similar strategy. A full example that populates the variable `result` is given below:

```
import re

w = ["Li$_3$O$^cat$", "Al$_2$O$_3$", "ZnO", "H$_2$O+O$^3$"]
w = str(w)

result = re.sub(r'\$_([^$]*)\$', r'<sub>\1</sub>', w)
result = re.sub(r'\$\^([^$]*)\$', r'<sup>\1</sup>', result)

print result
```

With the final output being:

```
['Li<sub>3</sub>O<sup>cat</sup>', 'Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>', 'ZnO', 'H<sub>2</sub>O+O<sup>3</sup>']
```

That being said, if the full set of substitutions that need to be done are more complex than this, you may want to store the substitution rules in some sort of data structure. For example:

```
import re

def substitute(rules, input):
  """Return a string with substitution performed on given input

  rules -- dict specifying the substitution rules
  input -- input string to be substituted
  """

  result = input
  for k, v in rules.iteritems():
    re_str = r'\$' + re.escape(k) + r'([^$]*)\$'
    sub_str = r'<%s>\1</%s>' % (v, v)
    result = re.sub(re_str, sub_str, result)
  return result

rules = {
  '_': 'sub',
  '^': 'sup'
}

w = ["Li$_3$O$^cat$", "Al$_2$O$_3$", "ZnO", "H$_2$O+O$^3$"]
print substitute(rules, str(w))
```

Output:

```
['Li<sub>3</sub>O<sup>cat</sup>', 'Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>', 'ZnO', 'H<sub>2</sub>O+O<sup>3</sup>']
```

Note that the above solutions do not deal with nested substitutions. These could be handled using more advanced regular expression features, like [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), or [full parsers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) if needed.

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry about all the confusion

Comment: @ZachThomas no problem. Does my answer meet your needs?

Comment: The end result that you are describing is what I am looking for. However, when I delete the two if statements and replace them with re.sub(r'\$_([^$]*)\$', r'<sub>\1</sub>', w)
re.sub(r'\$^([^$]*)\$', r'<sup>\1</sup>', w), the resulting string is unchanged and prints ['Li$_3$O$^cat$', 'Al$_2$O$_3$', 'ZnO', 'H$_2$O+O$_3$']

Comment: would you add the code to your response that worked for you? Maybe I am missing something

Comment: @ZachThomas I've updated my answer with a full working example

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

With regex, you can replace only the first occurrence using `count=1` parameter, with those 2 statements:

```
w = re.sub(r"\$_","<sub>",w,count=1)
w = re.sub(r"\$","</sub>",w,count=1)
```

(note the escaping of the `$` sign)

Another way is to use `str.partition` which splits according to left part, separator, right part, and rebuild a string using a new separator:

```
parts = w.partition("$_")
w = parts[0]+"<sub>"+parts[2]
parts = w.partition("$")
w = parts[0]+"</sub>"+parts[2]
```

or

```
w = "<sub>".join(w.partition("$_")[::2])
w = "</sub>".join(w.partition("$")[::2])
```

Comment: What about the closing `</sub>`?

Comment: edited, could have been figured out, but solution wasn't complete.

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry about all the confusion

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following which uses a function to decide which replacement to do for each type:

```
import re

def replace(r):
    if r.group(1):
        return "<sub>{}</sub>".format(r.group(1))
    else:
        return "<sup>{}</sup>".format(r.group(2))

w = ["Li$_3$O$^cat$", "Al$_2$O$_3$", "ZnO", "H$_2$O+O$_3$"]

for text in w:
    print re.sub(r"\$_(.*?)\$|\$\^(.*?)\$", replace, text)
```

Giving you:

```
Li<sub>3</sub>O<sup>cat</sup>
Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>
ZnO
H<sub>2</sub>O+O<sub>3</sub>
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
output = [re.sub(r"\$_(.*?)\$|\$\^(.*?)\$", replace, t) for t in w]
```

Comment: I think the expected output is: `Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>`

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry about all the confusion